# Inserting records with a composite key in an ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, composite-primary-key

I'm building an API with a subresource that looks like this:

```
/api/v1/journies/{journeyId}/logs/{logId}
```

I've made the `Log` model have a composite key based on `Id` and `JourneyId`:

```
public class Log
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Journey Journey { get; set; }
}
```

I've done this so I can make my resources look like this:

```
/api/v1/journies/1/logs/1
/api/v1/journies/1/logs/2
/api/v1/journies/2/logs/1
/api/v1/journies/2/logs/2
```

Basically so that the IDs of the logs start from 1 on every journey.

To try to make this work when I `POST` a new log entry, I've written this controller action:

```
[Route("api/v1/journies/{journeyId}/logs", Name="PostLog")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostLog(int journeyId, Log log)
{
    log.JourneyId = journeyId;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Logs.Add(log);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetLog", new { journeyId = journeyId, logId = log.Id }, log);
}
```

My thought process here is that I'm giving Entity Framework the `JourneyId` for the record, and I assume it will calculate the next incrementing `Id` for the record itself.

When I make a `POST` request to this action though, the following exception gets thrown:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Logs' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm guessing this is being thrown because I'm setting `log.JourneyId` to an implicit value?

What do I need to do different to make this work?

Comment: I think you are trying to insert a PK which is turned off in your model.
It's like having a db table with an PK set to autoincrement and you try to insert manually a PK.

Comment: Did you try loading the Journey entity instead of setting the `JourneyId`: `log.Journey = db.Journies.FindById(journeyId);`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: just tried that and got the same error, with and without setting `log.JourneyId`.

Comment: @Legends that sounds like it could be the cause, any idea how to achieve what I want without setting the PK field myself?

Comment: If you don't set it will nevertheless have a value of "0", what do you use DB First?

Comment: I'm using Code First EF.